# How to prove that TE modes cannot exist in microstrip structures?

Tags: antenna

I kow that the modes in microstrips are TM modes. I know that we have boundary conditions to see if the mode exists.

What boundary conditions do I need to use for TE and TM?
Where do I put them in the equation below?

I know that for TM , Hz = 0 and
for TE, Ez = 0. How do I see that there is no TE mode in a microstrip?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the image is cut from some microstrip resonator tutorial. The metal surfaces are in YZ planes, their distance h is in X-direction in this image.

Waves which propagate in the insulation layer  must have E perpendicular with the metal surfaces except in case h is at least a half of the wavelength. So thick microstrips work unpredictably, so only Ex can be non-zero. Magnetic field is in XY-plane. If we tried somehow to feed a signal whic has non-zero Ez or Ey those components would be shorted by the metal surfaces. If h were at least half of the wavelength zigzag reflection between the metal surfaces would be possible, but that possibility is excluded to keep the behaviour predictable.

These things are actually the same as in TEM waves which propagate along microstrip transmission lines. The propagation of the wave is well predictable when the Y-width of the line is small, only line length in Z-direction can be a substantial part of the wavelength or several wavelengths.

Resonators can have waves propagating as well to Y and Z directions. Those waves can have both Y and Z magnetic field components. Hx=0. The name of the class of the possible waveforms is settled to "TMx" which obviously is a successful choice. It recalls that this is not a stripline transmission line, but resonator and can have waves which propagate in YZ plane - a difference to TEM waves which propagate to Z direction.

Why there's no TE waves in microstrip resonator? Answer: The possible waves have already got a name - TMx covers them all as long as h is less than half of the wavelength.  Nobody has wanted to spoil his name in publicity by presenting equations for impossible waves and inventing name TE for them.

About boundary conditions:

This is not at all clear. Actually the metal planes and the insulation layers are a complex boundary structure. Practical engineers make simplifications such as the fields do not bulge out of the gap between the metals. To stop YZ plane magnetic field in our thoughts we assume that there's H=0 and Ey=Ez=0 at the edges. In some texts they write it "magnetic wall"

WARNING: Metal tube waveguides have TE waveforms. If you see somewhere text "TE or TM waveform" do not assume anything before you also know the structure geometry. TM in a stripline resonator is totally different thing than TM in metal tube waveguides.

Comment: Could you please tell me what equations we use and what boundary conditions,to show that TE cannot be formed?(only TM01)

Comment: Just noticed that you have given name TE to waves which have Ez=0 end expect someone here shows why waves with Ez=0 are impossible.  The included image presents TMx waveforms which have Ez=0, so there's a contradiction with the  already established naming.  Check the coordinate axle directions. Maybe you want to prove something else.

Comment: So basicly what you say that our boundary conditions is electric field zero tangential to the PEC planes,and magnetic field normal to the PEC is zero at the edge of the PEC (magnetic wall) correct?

Comment: @rocko445  See this at first: Because h is short when compared to wavelength in practical microstrips, there cannot be much field strength variations when one moves straight from a conductor plane to ground plane. That makes automatically impossible those waveforms where zero tangential total E at metal surface is got by reflection ==> E must be perpendicular with metal i.e. only Ex is . nonzero.

Comment: @rocko445 (continued)  The edge condition  is a simplification. I saw a lecture note which seems to try to explain the case you see problematic. It has even got a (poor quality) copy of one your image. I have not that problematic book but the explaining lesson is here. http://www.acad-antenna.co.il/pics/ACAD/_thumbs/21_Microstrip_2.pdf Check if it helps. The boundary conditions for the existing wave are shown at pages 14-15.

Comment: Hello User2877001,Very good article.
It says in equations 21.21 and 21.42 basicly they say that TM001 mode has E field onX direction and H field in Y direction,and they both from standing wave pattern along Z axes. but In the formal definition of TM mode they say.
"n the Transverse Magnetic (TM) mode, the magnetic field is transverse to the direction of propagation while the electric field is normal to the direction of propagation"

transverse=paralel,the magnetic field is not paralel to the direction of propogation.So how its a TM mode based on the formal definition?
Thanks.

Comment: @rocko445  transverse to propagation direction is the same as normal to the propagation. If the wave propagation happens to z-direction, everything in xy-plane is both normal and transverse to the propagation direction.

Comment: what is the difference between normal and transverse?

Comment: Nothing as directions here. Transverse means 90 degrees off from the wave propagation direction. Z. That's also x and y and everything in XY plane which all are normal to the Z axis.

Comment: Hello user287001,could you please draw a simple thing.so i could visualise your words? Thanks.

Comment: There's already a good drawing - your first image. h is the direction of x, W is the direction of y, L is the direction of  z. Electric field has no room to be anything else but in x direction. Magnetic field must be in XY plane. The wave bounces forth and back, the propagation can happen only in XY plane. Case TMx010 is possible at the lowest frequency. Bouncing happens between planes sized (W)x(h). to z-direction. The image shows the standing wave amplitude pattern of the oscillating electric field. Magnetic field at the edges is simplified in writers thinking to have only y-component .

Comment: yes,we have electric field in X (h) direction,We have H field is normal to it in the y direction (W) direction,and both of them form standing wave in the Z(L) direction.So what makes it a TM mode?

Comment: It's not TM, it 's named TMx and the person who has named it TMx  has made it TMx. I guess he would have an excuse if he happened to be captured by a brutal tribe who cannot accept the given name:  "Try to understand that I cannot call it TEM because that name is already in general use for other applications with less simplifying assumptions, but let's call it TMx because the magnetic field is just sideways 90 degrees when compared to the propagation direction - that means transverse - and it has nothing in x direction.

Comment: So its a type of TEM mode.So we have both electric and magnetic 90 degrees to each other and 90 degrees to propogation direction in the Z-direction(i.e L direction)

Comment: In higher frequencies the total field can have also wave component which propagates to y direction and bounces between the (L)x(h) -sized edges. The lowest frequency single mode version of it is TMx001.

Comment: but in our case its a TMx01 TEM mode with no electric and magnetic field in the propogation direction z(L) correct?
our electric is at x(h) the magnetic is at y(W) correct?

Comment: That's TEM but only approximately. It's imagined to stop to the edges which isn't true, but gives reasonably good engineering results. The imagined wavetight magnetic walls are non-existent in reality but quite good approximation due the high permittivity of the insulator. In antenna applications the the radiation (which would be impossible with wavetight walls) is approximated by losses. Bouncing wave finally decays due losses and radiation out means more loss than metal resistance and lossy insulator.